# Does the product of the marginal densities has some relation with the joint density?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Be specific, do we have
$$f_X(x)f_Y(y) \geq f_{X,Y}(x,y)?$$
It is very easy to find a counterexample in the discrete case. So under the continuous case, and under what assumptions will we have this inequality?

Many thanks for any comment.

Comment: I assume you mean will the inequality holds for every $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. First, the answer is no if the inequality is strict. Note that every pdf will integrate to $1$, so you cannot have one pdf dominate the other over the entire domain. Of course for any pdf, you can freely change countably many points without affecting the volume under the pdf, so the weak inequality can be hold technically. Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: @BGM Thanks~ What I want is under what kind of conditions this inequality will hold for the general continuous case?

Comment: @Nan BGM has showed that the strict version can’t be true globally. $f_X(x)f_Y(y)< f_{X,Y}(x,y),$ just means that the density is higher than if they were independent. For instance, if we have zero mean normals  with positive correlation, then it will be higher in the first and third quadrants and lower in the second and fourth.